# Adding additional border to a hovered element that is floated inside a fixed with container?

Tags: css

I have a grid of tiles, what I want to be able to do is hover a tile and add a 3px border and keep the tile positioned correctly without disrupting the other tiles around it. At the moment I'm not completely sure how this can be achieved? Can this be achieved using floats or would I have to absolutely position each of the tiles and then increase the z-index of the hovered tile so it stands out above the rest?

Also the tile dimensions have to remain the same and the border has to be outside the tile and not inset.

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Z7TwF/

Answer (score 1):

On the :hover selector you need to remove the combined width of the borders:

```
li:hover{border:3px solid #f00; width: 44px; height: 44px;}
```

When you add a border to an element, it increases its dimensions. So when you hover the element, removing the combined width of the borders on the dimension attributes will fix the issue.

http://jsfiddle.net/Z7TwF/2/

---

Another solution is to change the box-sizing method:

```
li
{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

This in essence tells the browser to calculate the width of the borders in with the width of the element, preventing the offset you had in your original example.

http://jsfiddle.net/Z7TwF/3/

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. Sorry I should have added that the dimensions need to remain the same. Thanks for the second tip but the border also has to be outer and not inset